# How can I apply find_all 2 times to parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to make a web scraper that will scrape website for

with class product_cat-riso, It finds all the

's, but then I want to check if they are in stock - the ones that are in stock also have class 'instock' as addition to product_cat-riso. I have tried to use filter() here, but not working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://eshop.ciernediery.sk/'
req = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
lst = soup.find_all('li', class_='product_cat-riso')

def fltr(item):
    if 'instock' in item:
        return True
    else:
        return False
in_stock = filter(fltr, lst)
for item in in_stock:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal **working** code (URL...)

Comment: my bad, i did not copy it

Comment: are you sure this is the right website? I can't find any of the classes you mention. **lst** returns empty

Comment: I see just 1 similar which is `product_cat-risografiky` - is this the  right url?

Comment: You are right, I was just trying some testing and forgot to put it back, but I had it on risografiky when trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to work on assumption you only listed part of one of the class names and that full class name is `product_cat-risografiky` (single from multi-value class). I would be tempted to abbreviate the logic of `fltr()` and then ensure the test of membership is on the list of class values for the tag rather than the tag object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def fltr(item):
    return 'instock' in item['class']

url = 'https://eshop.ciernediery.sk/'
req = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
lst = soup.find_all('li', class_='product_cat-risografiky')
# lst = soup.select('li.product_cat-risografiky')

in_stock = filter(fltr, lst)

for item in in_stock:
    print(item)
```

Comment: i dont understand how the item['class'] works, how does it know what is the items class ?

Comment: It is a bs4 tag method which will return the class names associated with the tag. You know there will be at least one as class was used to retrieve the tag list.